# Django: create database user on user-create

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-users

I need to implement a functionality that creates a postgres DB-user when a django-user is created in the admin interface (DB-user should have same username and password).
I figured out that I could use Signals to execute a script when a user is created, but the problem is I cannot get the raw password of the user.

So is there a way to get the raw password of a django user in this context?
And if not, what would be the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad design. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The client wants to have this logic, so users created in django can also access the database remotely in tools like Excel or Tableau with the same user information.